# Why does this static Instance return null when instantiating with 'as Gameobject' in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the following class to reference Audio Assets in my game

```
public class AudioAssets : MonoBehaviour{

private static AudioAssets _Instance;

public static AudioAssets Instance
{
    get
    {
        if (_Instance == null)
        {
            _Instance = (Instantiate(Resources.Load("AudioAssets")) as GameObject).GetComponent<AudioAssets>();
        }
        return _Instance;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately when I tested this with the following

```
AudioManager.AudioManagerInstance.PlayClipTest(AudioAssets.Instance.Molotov);
```

it throws a null exception inside the If statement.

What I am really confused about is I have an identical class `GameAssets` which has the exact signature as this one and works without a flaw

They are both located inside resources [image]

I've tried a lot but I can't get behind why one of these is working but the other isn't.
Am I missing something obvious here? Would really appreciate some help!

Comment: If `AudioAssets` is based on unity's `Object` class then you aren't supposed to do null checks in the typical manner (ie `AudioAssets == null`. You are supposed to do `if (!AudioAssets)` instead. See [this unity article](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NullReferenceException.html). And it must be that `AudioAssets` is based on Unity's `Object` since you are using `Instantiate` to set it up.

Comment: Also to be clear on "it throws a null exception inside the If statement" do you mean the condition or the body of the if statement?

Comment: I expect that `Instantiate(Resources.Load("AudioAssets"))` is returning something that can't be cast to `GameObject`. I don't do Unity though so I could be wrong.

Comment: @Llama If the issue is in the body then you would be right in that case. The problem with using `as` instead of the typical explicit cast.

Comment: @OmarAbdelBari the null is thrown on the line inside the if statement, so the body

Comment: Then @Llama is correct. I suggest avoid using `as` casting unless you know it's possible to get null in some situations and are ready to handle it. I know the Unity docs are littered with misuse of `as`.

A stack trace with the exact line that it's pointing to would be helpful for the future.

Comment: What is the value of `AudioAssets.Instance.Molotov`?

Comment: Make sure you are correctly referencing the resource you are trying to load as per [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html) unity page and the path reflects the path relative to `Assets/Resources/`

Comment: @OmarAbdelBari it is an audio clip assigned in the inspector on this class and the prefab AudioAssets

Comment: AFAIK you can't set private (without `[SerializeField]`) or static properties in the inspector. If it were the case why even have a getter that tries to load `Asset/Resources/AudioAssets`. (I asked before what was the path of the resource but it's right there in the code doh!)

Comment: @OmarAbdelBari You were right, the issue was within the Resources.Load. I found a weird but I guess working workaround. Since GameAssets does work, I simply load the AudioAssets through GameAssets with GameAssets.Instance.AudioAssets and the audio is correctly loaded and played now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The Answer

`Instantiate(Resources.Load("AudioAssets"))` is going to look for a file called `AudioAssets` in a `Resources` folder somewhere in the directory tree below `Assets` folder (see [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html)). If that file does not exist, `Instantiate(Resources.Load("AudioAssets")) as GameObject` will evaluate as null because of the use of the `as` keyword. Subsequently, invoking `GetComponent<AudioAssets>()` on `null` will result in `NullReferenceException`.

### Side note to avoid other weird issues:

- Any instances you have that are subclasses of Unity's `Object` should do null checks on the object itself (`Instance == null` should actually be `!Instance`). Otherwise, you might experience unexpected behaviour. See [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NullReferenceException.html) for more details.
- Avoid `as` like the plague. Unless you know there is are valid reasons for the item instantiated to be null and handle it appropriately to avoid a `NullReferenceException` use an explicit cast instead so the line would be `_Instance = ((GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load("AudioAssets"))).GetComponent<AudioAssets>();`. That way, if it's not able to cast what it tried to load, it will give you a more obvious exception indicating so.

Comment: Just to add: Also (and maybe even more) avoid the usage of `Resources` like the plague ^^ Unity's official statement in the [Best practices for `Resources`](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/assets-resources-and-assetbundles#5c7f8528edbc2a002053b5a7): **Don't use it!**

Comment: I recall trying it once as well and stopped. There is usually a better solution for whatever you are trying to do.